# How do i create a function to use a standard integer array or a unique pointer array without overloading?

Tags: arrays, function, c++11, pointers, smart-pointers

I'm trying to create a program that creates an array of a particular size and then extends that array by one. It also needs to display the first array before the function call and the new array after the function call.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

unique_ptr<int[]> newCopy(int arry[], int items)
{
    unique_ptr<int[]> p(new int[items + 1]);

    p[0] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < items; i++)
    {
        p[i + 1] = arry[i];
}

return p;

}

void displayArry(int arry[], int items)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < items; i++)
    {
       cout << arry[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 5;
    int myNumbers[SIZE] = {18, 27, 3, 14, 95};

    displayArry(myNumbers, SIZE);

    unique_ptr<int[]> newArry = newCopy(myNumbers, SIZE);

    //displayArry(newArry, SIZE + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE+1; i++)
    {
       cout << newArry[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would like the display function to display both the normal integer array and the smart pointer array without having to overload the function.

The display function works mostly as intended for only the standard integer array.
The extension function works and the new unique pointer array displays the correct values if I use a for loop inside of the main function, but I can't seem to figure out how to use both in the display function.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out by messing with different passing methods.

First I changed the displayArray() parameter of the array to a reference with *.

```
void displayArry(int arry[], int items)
```

changes to

```
void displayArry(int* arry, int items)
```

and then i added .get() to the end of the unique_ptr array like this:

```
displayArry(newArry, SIZE + 1);
```

changes to:

```
displayArry(newArry.get(), SIZE + 1);
```

This allows me to pass all the data by reference to the function and allows it to properly display either a normal array or a unique_ptr array.

If there are any thoughts on this, or ways that this should be done instead, or ways this could be done better, I'd appreciate the feedback.